# Convert 1D array into 2D JSON array with descriptions for each cell

Tags: php, arrays, json

*(please excuse any mistakes in terminology, I am not very familiar with json)*

I have an array of maps, with each cell containing map details *[map][details]*. When I encode the array into json I get a valid json representation of my array.

My question is how can I change from a 1D array for each map into a 2D array with cell descriptions such as "map_id" = "23" instead of just "23"?

```
$maps = UserMaps::getMapIDs($user_id);      // get map IDs user has access to 

$mapsData = array();                        // create new array to store data
foreach ($maps as $key => $value) {         // for maps user has access to
    $mapsData[] = Maps::getMap($maps[$key]['map_id']);  // push map data into new array
}

var_dump($mapsData);
if($mapsData == NULL) { echo "no maps to display"; }
return $mapsData;                           // return array with map data
```

I get the json by simply encoding with

```
json_encode(Maps::getAllMaps());
```

Should I turn the array into a 3D array [maps][detail][value] and then encode?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by converting the 2D array into a 3D array before encoding. Here is the code bellow:

```
$maps = UserMaps::getMapIDs($user_id);              // get map IDs user has access to 

$mapsData = array();                                // create new array to store data from the maps
foreach ($maps as $key => $value) {                 // for each map user has access to
    $mapData = Maps::getMap($maps[$key]['map_id']);      // get map properties
    $map = array();
    for($i=0; $i<11; $i++){
        $property = array();            // create property array
        $property[] = $properties[$i];   // add property title
        $property[] = $mapData[$i];          // add value
        $map[] = $property;
    }
    $mapsData[] = $map;  // push map data into new array cell
}

// var_dump($mapsData);
if($mapsData == NULL) { echo "no maps to display"; }
return $mapsData;
```